# How can I use the string "watch" as a key in a JavaScript associative array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array declared like this:

```
var dict = [];
```

When I do this:

```
dict["watch"] = 0;
```

this expression alerts `NaN`

```
alert (dict["watch"]);
```

I know this is because `watch()` is a function that is part of the object prototype. Is there anyway around this so I can use any word as a key in my array?

I am using Firefox 3.6.6

Comment: If you're on Firefox, the only browser that has `Object.watch`, then why are you seeing a `NaN` instead of the `watch` function in your alert? I'm Firefox 3.6.6 too, and I see `function watch() { [native code] }`.

Comment: The problem was that somewhere in my code I wasn't checking that `dict["watch"]` is a function. One of the thing my code does is: `dict["watch"]++`, so it was trying to increment a function.

Comment: Thanks Anurag - I was unaware of that method. Handy to know for future reference. I assume it's unenumerable?

Comment: @lucideer - Anything added to `Object.prototype` has to be unenumerable, as it would otherwise show up in `for..in` loops, unless it's something that an application cannot live without :). It's a pretty handy way to monitor object changes without constantly polling them, and I hope all browsers added this to their arsenal of offerings.

Comment: @SimpleCoder - that explains the `NaN` :)

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. Just so you know, this is going to go into my latest project, a Bayesian spam filter written in JavaScript. If anyone is interested the link will be on my blog: http://mosttw.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var dict =
    {
        "watch": 0
    };

alert(dict["watch"]);
```

Comment: Marking yours as the right answer because you suggested something that worked sooner than the other answers

Answer (score 1):

Shorthand for associative arrays***** is curly-braces, rather than square ones:

```
var dict={};
dict["watch"] = 0;
```

Or simply:

```
var dict={ watch:0 };
```

******Technically javascript doesn't have "associative arrays", it has "objects" - but they work in effectively the same way for this specific purpose.*

Answer (score 1):

I found the root of the problem (of course it was 5 seconds after I asked my question):

My code checks that the key in `dict` is undefined or null before assigning a value like this:

```
 if (dict[key] == null)
      dict[key] = 0;
```

But since "watch" is part of the object prototype, `dict[key] == null` would never be true.

Edit:

However, even when I do this:

```
if (typeof dict[word] == "function" || dict[word] == null)
    dict[word] = 0;
```

the value of

```
dict["watch"]
```

is now `function watch(){ native code }` or something like that

**Got it:**

In my infinite wisdom, I had a similar mistake somewhere else in my code which I have now fixed. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

Try `dict = {}`. `[]` is for array literals, `{}` is for object literals, which are, more or less, hashes. It gets confusing, since you still use square brackets for indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you executing your code?  In Firefox 3.3.6, Chrome 5.0.375.99 beta, IE 8, and Safari 5, it alerts 0 for me.